# Use of "ironically" or "unironically" in indicating surprise

Tags: word-choice, irony

Take the following comment:

> "Married like a couple of hunters bound together" is the ironically cutest description of marriage I've ever heard

Which spawned a discussion on whether *ironically* was the right word to use, and if *unironically* was the correct word to use instead. The OP insists that

> that would imply it was expected, *ironically* shows it surprised me that the description was so cute

With someone else disagreeing, saying that

> The phrasing would be "That is unironically the cutest description of marriage I've ever heard".
>
> The fact that you're already emphasising and using *unironically* would show that it would generally be surprising for it to be cute, and that your sentence would read jokingly... which is why you use the word, to signal that you're being serious that it's cute.

With the OP saying

> To suggest to use "unironically" means I would sincerely view this as the cutest description as well as informally implying I expected it to be such.

Is there any insights as to which usage is more correct or if there is any mistakes in this discourse?

Answer (score 1):

To say that is should be "*unironically*" when the OP meant "*ironically*" is not correct. Whether the OP used it correctly depends on their aim.

**If** they only meant to say that they were surprised (or a fact was unexpected), this is not strictly the [meaning of "*ironically*"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ironically)

> in a way that is interesting, strange, or funny because of being very different from what you would expect

> in a way that suggests you mean the opposite of what you are saying, or are not serious

> in a way that is different or opposite from the result you would expect

The use is commonly "*Ironically, X*". For example, "*Ironically, they missed the train because they ran onto the platform in a hurry*". The aim and the outcome are direct opposites.

But the OP **may** be using the word correctly. The original sentence "X is the ironically Y" works if X and Y are opposite in their meaning or aim. It is up to the OP or readers whether "*hunters bound together*" and "*cutest*" are remarkably contradicting.

Finally, if the OP meant to say that they were not serious, that is also a meaning of the word "ironically" but is commonly used to describe a statement, rather than included in one.